# How to remove lightbox from a specific image?

Tags: html, css

I have lightbox turned on on all pages of a website. I want the lightbox to not work on some specific pages and want those images to open in a new page when a click is performed. Please guide me how can I do so. Thanks.

Comment: If you attaching light box with `rel="lightbox"` ? or else which approach you are using?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the lightbox to not work on some specific pages

All you have to do is to remove the script from that specific page.
The script looks something like this:

```
<script src='js/lightbox.js'></script>
```

> want those images to open in a new page when a click is performed

I have wrote an example below:

```
<a href='img/test.png' target='_blank'><img src='img/test.png'/></a>
```

This should work.

Comment: Your second example will open on the same page, not a new page. Use in conjunction with  target="_blank"